# how to delete value from a string variable

Tags: python, string, variables

I have designed a function which would take input name from RFID card and prints it. This variable `Username` is declared global so that I can use it in other functions. Now I want to use this variable in another function which will check if there is value stored in Username or not and performs the corresponding function. At the end of this function this variable should be deleted. so that it takes a new value next time and not use the previous value stored. Therefore I want to delete value stored in my variable so that it can take a new value every time. How can I do this?

```
def RFID_reading(a,b):
    global reader, Username

    while True:
        Starttime = time.time()
        try:
            id, Username = reader.read()
            print(Username)

def store_unknown(picture_list):

    if Username != "":
          j=0
          while j < len(picture_list):
          cv2.imwrite(f'{y}/{picture_list[j][2]}.png', picture_list[j] [0])
          j += 1
          Username == None
```

I have tried writing `Username == None` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `global Username` before the last line `Username == None`. This is to denote that you are aware and going to update the global variable's value.